# 2019 15” MacBook Pro - USB-C port not loading

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

One of my four USB-C ports is not loading.  I have done a soft reset, SMC reset, and zapped the NVRAM with no success.

Any suggestions to get this fixed? [image: System Report - USB]

Comment: Which two ports; the 2 on the left, right or one from each side?

Comment: Right side.  The first port (closest to screen) is not loading.  The second one is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify; on the right side, the *rear* port is not working, while the *forward* port on the same side works  If this is the case, it sounds like the physical port itself failed.

There are two USB controller chips on these models MacBook Pro; one on each side controlling the two USB-C ports in it’s proximity.  If one of the ports fails while the other functions then the USB controller is functional.  This sounds like a failure of the physical port itself or some of the circuitry connecting the port to the controller.

If you wish or need to use this port and the other three are insufficient for your needs, then it will need to go in for service.  There’s no software fix for this.

Comment: This is what I figured.. i cleaned the port externally the best I could. Given that these macs are not very service friendly, I wonder if that port can be fixed or its the hole board that needs replacing..

Comment: Since these are common components everything from the port to the USB controller can be replaced.  You just need to find a reputable shop that does board level work.

Comment: I replaced the USB C port and with a brand new one and issues persists.  This has to be some sort of software glitch

Comment: A tech replaced the *port* without doing diagnostics first?  Was it the port itself or the USB controller chip?  This isn’t a widespread problem, so why do you assume it’s software?

Comment: I replace the port myself.

Comment: In using this laptop, I have received notification that the USB ports were turned off due to power consumption.  To turn them reset them, was not as easy and most would tell you.. eg zap P ram and SMC reset.. it took a few tries.  So I am simply assuming that there is some glitch.  There are also quite a few cases of USB C ports on these macs having issues.